# Angular why use HttpInterceptor versus custom base request service

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

Why should I use an HttpInterceptor when I can implement all the functionality I want inside my custom base request service? I insert headers, handle errors, redirect...

It seems to me that an HttpInterceptor is useful only as an emergency solution for people that did not think ahead to wrap all their requests in a single service, to route all their requests through a single choke point.

Is there any other gain for using HttpInterceptors apart from preference?

Comment: interceptors are an easy global solution if you need some kind of action run on every http request, and that is what they're for. base services wrapping or extending the http client can be a bit cumbersome or annoying to maintain and work with. It's not like replacing the http client globally would be hard if you wrote a custom one anyway using a provider as an "emergency" solution if you suddenly needed all requests going through a service

Comment: Each interceptor is independant from the other ones, avoiding the need to put everything in the same service. And rewriting a complete HttpCLient clone, with its dozens of overloaded methods, just to intercept the calls looks way weirder to me. Plus you have to redo that for every project instead of using the documented HttpClient that every Angular developer knows (or at least, should know)

Comment: Angular interceptors can be provided by third-party (or in-house) libraries, and can intercept HTTP calls made by third-party (or in-house) libraries using the HttpClient.